# аналог background-attachment : fixed

Tags: javascript, css

`background-attachment : fixed` каждый раз при прокрутке вызывает операцию перерисовки что вызывает очень сильные тормоза и лаги. Мне нужен аналог этого свойства на javascript или css.

Comment: из `css` конечно, но я имею ввиду любым кроме этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body{
  position: relative;
}
body::before {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    will-change: transform;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Однако это только для body. но есть вариант по лучше.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
        $('#main').css('background-position', '0px ' + $(document).scrollTop() + 'px');
    });
```

Comment: Лучшесть второго варианта под вопросом :-) У вас на каждое событие скролла будет пересчет и работа с DOM. А если учесть, что при наличии плавной прокрутки браузер за одно движение колесом вызывает раз 10 событие скролла, то и подавно.

Comment: @Sevastopol' да, оба варианты не рациональны так как ответ который я отметил здесь требует работы с DOM при событии скролла (как @SashaOmelchenko) отметил. Лучшим вариантом будет создать блок с `position: fixed` который находится позади всех блоков, таким образом все будет происходить быстро но будет один недостаток - только один такой фон может существовать, что кстати достаточно просто исправить с помошью подмены картинок на определенном участке скролла.

Answer (score 1):

А вообще будет лучше использовать определенный параллакс, он и для телефонов будет работать) Это не к месту, но может надо

Comment: Да спасибо, я уже себе сам ответил. Это была так сказать "Шпаргалка"